# Button that generates error message on condition

Tags: javascript, html, button, error-messaging

I am trying to implement a button in HTML that calls a function on click, which checks whether a textinput is empty. If so (the information hasn't been entered), an error message for the input field should be generated.

I am experimenting with a button that doesn't submit the form. However, if you have a solution with a button that does submit the form (unless the string is empty), I'll gladly take it. In that case (and in any really) I would like to work with setCustomValidity, as I want an error message right away and not after the page reloads if that makes sense (because then the input in the form isn't kept).

This is what I have so far:

```
<p>
        <label for="image_info">Information</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="image_info" id="image_info">
    </p>

    <br>

    <button type="button" onclick="imageErrorMessage()">Check</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function imageErrorMessage(image_info){
        if(image_info === "")document.getElementById('image_info').setCustomValidity('Please enter your information.');
        else document.getElementById('image_info').setCustomValidity('')
        }
    </script>
```

Unfortunately something seems to be missing/wrong, as it doesn't work. I'm fairly new to Javascript so the mistake could be crystal clear and I wouldn't know.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were three problems:

- you were missing a lot of curly braces for the if statements (note: apparently these aren't required, but I prefer them for readability)
- you need to put `document.getElementById('image_info').reportValidity();` after the setCustomValidity
- you weren't sending any parameters to `imageErrorMessage`

```js
function imageErrorMessage(image_info){
  if(image_info == "") {
    document.getElementById('image_info').setCustomValidity('Please enter your information.');
    document.getElementById('image_info').reportValidity();
  } else {
    document.getElementById('image_info').setCustomValidity('')
    document.getElementById('image_info').reportValidity();
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label for="image_info">Information</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="image_info" id="image_info">
</p>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="imageErrorMessage(document.getElementById('image_info').value)">Check</button>
```

Comment: In JavaScript, `if` statements work without curly braces and they are not required

Comment: Although they are not required, they are highly recommended to improve readability. The criticism of missing curly braces is entirely valid but he should definitely add a remark that they aren't required.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked! It's really close to what I had before which is great, thanks. Also now I kind off understand the part about sending parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Some errors in your code:

- The HTML was in a paragraph instead of a [`<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form).
- You were not validating the field correctly
- You were not preventing submit of the form
- You were not presenting the error message to the user

My solution:

- Has a `<form>`
- Prevents submit of the form
- Checks the field
- Gives an error if empty, otherwise submits the form via JavaScript

```js
const $form = document.getElementById('form')
const $submit = document.getElementById('submitButton')
const $imageInfo = document.getElementById('image_info')

$submit.onclick = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()

  if (!$imageInfo.value) {
    $imageInfo.setCustomValidity('Please enter your information.')
    $imageInfo.reportValidity()
  } else {
    $form.submit()
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol';
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <label for="image_info">Information:</label>
  <input type="text" name="image_info" id="image_info">
  <button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Using `<p>` instead of `<form>` doesn't completely break it - it just doesn't submit anything anywhere. Also, op was using vanilla Javascript without any add-ons.

Comment: Just out of curiosity might I ask why you use dollar signs in front of your variable names?

Comment: @ΛRYΛN Also you might want to change your answer to resemble [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_required) as that would probably provide a better alternative to Lemondoge's solution, as you're already working with a form here.

Comment: @MerlinFejzuli that's one of my personal coding conventions in front-end JavaScript so that I can easily discern between HTML elements and plain number/string/object/array variables. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @ΛRYΛN Interesting, I might pick that up, thank you.

Comment: You broke it - gives `$form.submit is not a function` now

Comment: When I read your code it becomes clear to me how it works and when I try it via Run code snippet it works. However, I have basically copied and pasted it (in PyCharm, which I use) and it doesn't work. The error message isn't displayed, the button always submits the form.